# Swift Combine return Publisher from func

Tags: swift, combine, publisher

I want to return the publisher for a function if there is error in input params for it but its giving some compilation error.

Below is the function for the same.

```
func fetchList(input: String) -> AnyPublisher<List, Error> {
    guard let url = URL(string: input)  else {            
        return AnyPublisher(URLError(.cannotParseResponse))
    }
    //some call for to get the List which returns publisher
}
```

**Error**

`Cannot invoke initializer for type 'AnyPublisher<_, _>' with an argument list of type '(URLError)'`

**Summary**

How to create our publisher to return the error?

Thanks for any hint in the right direction.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`AnyPublisher` requires a `Publisher` as its initialiser argument, whereas you are giving it `URLError`. You probably mean to say "I want a publisher that publishes an error immediately". To do that, you use the [`Fail`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/fail) publisher:

```
return AnyPublisher(
    Fail<List, Error>(error: URLError(.cannotParseResponse))
)
```